# How to print email without printing the attachments in Outlook 2003

Tags: printing, microsoft-outlook-2003, attachments

Is there a way to print the email in the main windows without printing the attachments? When I right click on a new incoming email with attachments and I hit "Print", I get prompted to print the documents. I would need to print the email only without attachment and of course, without opening the email.